# Replication in mysql with many servers

Tags: mysql, replication

There are 3 shops.  In each of these is a mysql server.  I want all servers to synchronize their date if at least one server changes the date. I read a bit of literature and realized that I need master master replication. However, I must take into account the fact that one or more of the databases can work a couple of hours in offline mode (e.g. shut down Internet).  How will this work in this case? Will there be duplication of column with Primary key? if so then do I need to take this into account?

Advise me, please. I'm new to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If your Servers get out of sync they play back the events from the binlog, so as long you have all statements writen into your binlog, the master/slave is able to catch up. I had to catch up 12days without any problems, but in a cluster this is not what you want to happen.
And be careful when using "unsafe" statements, this are statements which the server can't reproduce on your master/slave setup.

Mysql Article on safe/unsafe statements - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rbr-safe-unsafe.html